# How to automaticaly calculate a new field (Column) in MS Access DB 2016 each month

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm using MS Access 2016 on a win10 platform. I have a table in Access `tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB` that has the months of the year as headers example: `OCT`, `NOV`, `DEC`, etc..

I have a query that calculates the total of the months dollar value for all my Organizations that money is sent to.

I am needing help modifying my code in my query to automatically add the next month field to that calculation. I currently have to go in the query and modify it every month.

Here is what I am using so far:

```
OB_Plan: Nz([Oct],0)+Nz([NOV],0)+Nz([DEC],0)+Nz([JAN],0)
```

This is placed as an expression in my query. So I would like a way to automatically add the next month in the expression. example:

```
OB_Plan: Nz([Oct],0)+Nz([NOV],0)+Nz([DEC],0)+Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)
```

I'm thinking I may need to make this a function and call the function in the expression.

Any ideas would be helpful.
SQL Script modified:

```
SELECT tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.Record_ID, ([tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data]![Directorate] & " " & "(" & [tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data]![FUND_CENTER] & ")") AS Directorate, tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.SAG, tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.MDEP, Calc_OB_Plan([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC]) AS OB_Plan, [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE]![AFP-FMEDDW] AS Current_AFP, [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE]![ALLT-FMEDDW] AS Allotment_YTD, [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE].TITLE
FROM tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data INNER JOIN [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE] ON (tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.MDEP = [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE].MDEP) AND (tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.SAG = [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE].SAG)
GROUP BY tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.Record_ID, ([tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data]![Directorate] & " " & "(" & [tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data]![FUND_CENTER] & ")"), tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.SAG, tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.MDEP, "", [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE]![AFP-FMEDDW], [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE]![ALLT-FMEDDW], [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE].TITLE;
```

Comment: Any reason you need two independent solutions? @LeeMac and June, may have worked together (less effort for them, maybe more value for you ;( ). Please read [ask] and explain from where the monthly sums appear. Isn't each transaction stored, with the value and date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason that you are finding this difficult to achieve using standard MS Access functionality is because your database does not adhere to [database normalisation rules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics).

The moment that you find yourself hard-coding month names into query expressions and consequently modifying the structure of your queries each month is a red flag that your database design should change.

In your case, based on the information you have provided, I would suggest defining either `Month` (preferably as an integer) or, better yet, a `Date` field in your table, with the data for each month appearing as **separate records** in the table, rather than on a single record.

Following this change, selection becomes simple, as you can easily calculate the months or date range that you wish to select within the selection criteria of your queries, **without the need to modify the query definition going forward**.

Without such redesign, the solutions will be ugly, for example:

```sql
select
    choose
    (
        month(date()),
        Nz([JAN],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0)+Nz([JUN],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0)+Nz([JUN],0)+Nz([JUL],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0)+Nz([JUN],0)+Nz([JUL],0)+Nz([AUG],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0)+Nz([JUN],0)+Nz([JUL],0)+Nz([AUG],0)+Nz([SEP],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0)+Nz([JUN],0)+Nz([JUL],0)+Nz([AUG],0)+Nz([SEP],0)+Nz([OCT],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0)+Nz([JUN],0)+Nz([JUL],0)+Nz([AUG],0)+Nz([SEP],0)+Nz([OCT],0)+Nz([NOV],0),
        Nz([JAN],0)+Nz([FEB],0)+Nz([MAR],0)+Nz([APR],0)+Nz([MAY],0)+Nz([JUN],0)+Nz([JUL],0)+Nz([AUG],0)+Nz([SEP],0)+Nz([OCT],0)+Nz([NOV],0)+Nz([DEC],0)
    )
from
    tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
```

Or:

```sql
select sum(t.amount)
from
(
    select 1 as mon, Nz([JAN],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 2 as mon, Nz([FEB],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 3 as mon, Nz([MAR],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 4 as mon, Nz([APR],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 5 as mon, Nz([MAY],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 6 as mon, Nz([JUN],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 7 as mon, Nz([JUL],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 8 as mon, Nz([AUG],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 9 as mon, Nz([SEP],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 10 as mon, Nz([OCT],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 11 as mon, Nz([NOV],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
    union
    select 12 as mon, Nz([DEC],0) as amount
    from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
) t
where 
    t.mon <= month(date())
```

Or, as a VBA function:

```vb
Function Calc_OB_Plan(vJan, vFeb, vMar, vApr, vMay, vJun, vJul, vAug, vSep, vOct, vNov, vDec) As Double
    Dim Arr()
    Arr = Array(vJan, vFeb, vMar, vApr, vMay, vJun, vJul, vAug, vSep, vOct, vNov, vDec)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Month(Date) - 1
        Calc_OB_Plan = Calc_OB_Plan + Nz(Arr(i), 0)
    Next i
End Function
```

Which could be called from your SQL query in the following way:

```sql
select Calc_OB_Plan([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC]) as OB_Plan
from tbl_OB_PLAN_ALLT_DISTRIB
```

### EDIT:

Since you are grouping by all fields, without any aggregation functions, you can replace the `group by` clause with a `select distinct` to obtain the same result more efficiently, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.Record_ID, 
    ([tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data]![Directorate] & " " & "(" & [tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data]![FUND_CENTER] & ")") AS Directorate, 
    tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.SAG, 
    tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.MDEP, 
    Calc_OB_Plan([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC]) AS OB_Plan, 
    [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE]![AFP-FMEDDW] AS Current_AFP, 
    [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE]![ALLT-FMEDDW] AS Allotment_YTD, 
    [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE].TITLE
FROM 
    tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data INNER JOIN [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE] ON
    tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.MDEP = [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE].MDEP AND 
    tbl_OB_Plan_ALLT_DISTRIB_Data.SAG = [001-FINAL_INTEGRATION_TABLE].SAG
```

Comment: true to the fact the Database is not designed to the proper normalization rules. im just trying to make whats in there work. As far as that goes The first option that you provided, do i just add that in the Field portion of my query (example: Expression1: Select choose {paste the rest of code here} and the run my query? Or do i put that in a Module as a Function? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since the number of characters in the expression will likely exceed the maximum permitted within the design view, you'll need to modify the SQL for your query, substituting the `choose` expression in place of the existing expression for the `OB_Plan` column.

Comment: I get an Error the syntax of the subquery in the expression is incorrect. (Check the subquery's syntax and enclose the subquery in parentheses.)

Comment: the error i see now from investigating is that your statement is correct length of characters exceeds the limit so it cut it off. i didnt see your post until i refreshed the page.

Comment: If you're inserting this into your existing query, as noted, you should only be using the `choose` expression, not the entire `select` query.

Comment: so how would you suggest i call the SQL from the Expression i already created? ```OB_Plan: =SQL```

Comment: My DB knowledge is limited I do apologize for not getting this.

Comment: where would you suggest i Place the above Select Choose code? I would say i am a little confused as to where to place it and configure my query in the design view .

Comment: Turning this into a Function. How would i go about that. what would the structure of the Function script look like i was thinking of putting it into some form of ```IF statement```.

Comment: ```If Month(Date(), True) = "OCT" Then

Comment: ```[Name of my function] = Nz([OCT],0),ElseIf Month(Date(), True) = "NOV" Then  [Name of my function] = Nz([OCT],0) + Nz([NOV],0) etc....```

Comment: First, view your current query in SQL view rather than Design View. Then, identify the section of code in the `select` clause which precedes `As OB_Plan` and replace that section of code with the `choose ( ... )` section of code from my post. Note that you'll need to run the query from SQL view as Design View won't support that many characters.

Comment: @BrianBlanton I have updated my answer to include an additional option.

Comment: im adding a screen shot since i am getting an error

Comment: i put the Function in and now when i try an call it i get an error this is how i am calling it

Comment: [OB_Plan: Calc_OB_Plan(Month(Date()))] is this not correct.

Comment: Don't post code as a screenshot. I have already shown how to call the function as part of my answer. Please repay the time I have invested in helping you by taking some time to study my suggestions and understand how the code works.

Comment: as I am not an expert in this i am doing what i can to learn from what you suggest and implement it all at the same time. I posted the code as a screen shot because i couldnt fit it in this tiny window of very few characters to add a comment. With that i see the function you posted and i added the Call Command into the SQL view screen and it give me an error " Your Query doesnt include the specified expression 'Calc_OB_Plan([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[AUG],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC]) as OB_Plan' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: I'm not expecting you to be an expert by any means, but only to consider the information provided before responding stating that it doesn't work. The error *"Your Query doesnt include the specified expression (...) as part of an aggregate function"* means that since your query uses aggregation (i.e. grouping by one or more fields), you will either need to either group by the calculated expression or enclose it within an aggregate function. You can edit your original question to include the full SQL code as a code block.

Comment: I just posted my SQL of the query any thoughs. and i do greatly appreciate all the time and help you have provided. Thank you.

Comment: @LeeMac Checked OP's profile and noticed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59902488/how-to-make-a-public-function-return-sum-value-based-off-current-month-in-ms-ac ?

Comment: @ComputerVersteher Thank you - I noticed that question too (and hoped I wasn't wasting my time continuing with this one), but thought I'd at least see it through to the end.