# How to make a Public Function return SUM value based off current Month in ms access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code that i am trying to use however when the query calls it it returns a blank column of data. so on it i am trying to add the number value in each column and adding a new column each month with the math formula.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB()
Dim OCT As String
Dim NOV As String
Dim DEC As String
Dim JAN As String
Dim FEB As String
Dim MAR As String
Dim APR As String
Dim MAY As String
Dim JUN As String
Dim JUL As String
Dim AUG As String
Dim SEP As String

OCT = Nz([OCT], 0)
NOV = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0)
DEC = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0)
JAN = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0)
FEB = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0)
MAR = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0) + Nz([MAR], 0)
APR = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0) + Nz([MAR], 0) + Nz([APR], 0)
MAY = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0) + Nz([MAR], 0) + Nz([APR], 0) + Nz([MAY], 0)
JUN = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0) + Nz([MAR], 0) + Nz([APR], 0) + Nz([MAY], 0) + Nz([JUN], 0)
JUL = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0) + Nz([MAR], 0) + Nz([APR], 0) + Nz([MAY], 0) + Nz([JUN], 0) + Nz([JUL], 0)
AUG = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0) + Nz([MAR], 0) + Nz([APR], 0) + Nz([MAY], 0) + Nz([JUN], 0) + Nz([JUL], 0) + Nz([AUG], 0)
SEP = Nz([OCT], 0) + Nz([NOV], 0) + Nz([DEC], 0) + Nz([JAN], 0) + Nz([FEB], 0) + Nz([MAR], 0) + Nz([APR], 0) + Nz([MAY], 0) + Nz([JUN], 0) + Nz([JUL], 0) + Nz([AUG], 0) + Nz([SEP], 0)


If MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "October" Then
    FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = OCT
    ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "November" Then
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = NOV
        ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "December" Then
            FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = DEC
            ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "January" Then
                FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = JAN
                ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "February" Then
                    FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = FEB
                    ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "March" Then
                        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = MAR
                        ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "April" Then
                            FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = APR
                            ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "May" Then
                                FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = MAY
                                ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "June" Then
                                    FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = JUN
                                    ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "July" Then
                                        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = JUL
                                        ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "August" Then
                                            FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = AUG
                                            ElseIf MonthName(Month(Date), False) = "September" Then
                                                FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = SEP

End If

End Function
```

I am calling this function from an expression in the query with it creating its own field in the query. So in the query design view in a blank field i put in **OB_PLAN: FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB()**. then in the Group By i selected **SUM**. not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: If you want numeric data then declare variables as a number type, not String. Use SELECT CASE instead of nested If Then ElseIf. Are the month names in brackets fields in table? Don't give variables same name as fields. Calling from query won't work because function doesn't know where [Oct], etc. are, in fact it should error.

Comment: so ```Dim OCT As Integer``` etc....

Comment: Integer or Long or Double depending on data. I would have expected function to error but since it is just returning blank something else is issue. Did not answer my question nor respond to other comments.

Comment: Sorry for overlooking your question. Yes they are Fields in a Table and the data in the field is a number (dollar value). So first i will change how i have them declared Next i will change the variables names so they dont match. ill be right back, making changes. again i am sorry for not seeing your question.

Comment: This public function in a general module will not find those fields. Either open a recordset in the function and reference recordset fields or put function behind form or report so it can see fields with `Me!Oct` and call function from textbox instead of query. Instead of grouping and summing in query, can do this in report using Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calc in textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a function in a general module to process data from a table and return value to query, then need to pass criteria to function via argument and open a recordset of data. Something like:

```
Public Function FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB(intID As Integer) As Long
Dim dblOCT As Double
Dim dblNOV As Double
Dim dblDEC As Double
Dim dblJAN As Double
Dim dblFEB As Double
Dim dblMAR As Double
Dim dblAPR As Double
Dim dblMAY As Double
Dim dblJUN As Double
Dim dblJUL As Double
Dim dblAUG As Double
Dim dblSEP As Double
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ID=" & intID)

With rs
    dblOCT = Nz(!OCT, 0)
    dblNOV = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0)
    dblDEC = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0)
    dblJAN = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0)
    dblFEB = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0)
    dblMAR = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0) + Nz(!MAR, 0)
    dblAPR = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0) + Nz(!MAR, 0) + Nz(!APR, 0)
    dblMAY = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0) + Nz(!MAR, 0) + Nz(!APR, 0) + Nz(!MAY, 0)
    dblJUN = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0) + Nz(!MAR, 0) + Nz(!APR, 0) + Nz(!MAY, 0) + Nz(!JUN, 0)
    dblJUL = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0) + Nz(!MAR, 0) + Nz(!APR, 0) + Nz(!MAY, 0) + Nz(!JUN, 0) + Nz(!JUL, 0)
    dblAUG = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0) + Nz(!MAR, 0) + Nz(!APR, 0) + Nz(!MAY, 0) + Nz(!JUN, 0) + Nz(!JUL, 0) + Nz(!AUG, 0)
    dblSEP = Nz(!OCT, 0) + Nz(!NOV, 0) + Nz(!DEC, 0) + Nz(!JAN, 0) + Nz(!FEB, 0) + Nz(!MAR, 0) + Nz(!APR, 0) + Nz(!MAY, 0) + Nz(!JUN, 0) + Nz(!JUL, 0) + Nz(!AUG, 0) + Nz(!SEP, 0)
End With

Select Case Month(Date))
    Case 10
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblOCT
    Case 11
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblNOV
    Case 12
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblDEC
    Case 1
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblJAN
    Case 2
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblFEB
    Case 3
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblMAR
    Case 4
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblAPR
    Case 5
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblMAY
    Case 6
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblJUN
    Case 7
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblJUL
    Case 8
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblAUG
    Case 9
        FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB = dblSEP
End Select
End Function
```

Call function in query like:
`SELECT tablename.*, FCalcMnthALLTDISTRIB([ID]) AS OB_PLAN FROM tablename;`

Comment: your a god send. thanks so much. i replaced tablenames with my tbls and it worked. thank you

Comment: @June7 `Integer`will most likely overflow soon, as OP stores dollar value for all his Organizations, see similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898124/how-to-automaticaly-calculate-a-new-field-column-in-ms-access-db-2016-each-mon. And all in the code screams`Dry`me with an array whose index represents the month!

Comment: I had not seen that question which does have a valid solution. I agree database design is not normalized but I was avoiding climbing on soapbox. Yes, Long or Double would be better variable types, edited answer. Array is certainly an option.